# Finding correct combination of functions

Tags: functions, combinatorics, list-manipulation, sorting

I am trying to write code where I have an array $S$ or numbers in any order `[5,4,2,1,....]`

Then I have a specific set of functions that I can write. `F1,F2,`.....

I also have a set of arrays that would be a solution if the array looked like it

I want to write code specifically that takes the array and tries `F1[S]` then tries `F2[S]` then `F3[S]` then try `F1[F1[S]]` and keep trying growing combinations until it finds one in the solution set then it can print out the combination of functions that found the solution

The problem I am actually working on is the [burnt pancake problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting).

Where an array could be 3 long and be the three number in any order. Then it would try 3 functions

```
F1[S]={-S[1],S[2],S[3]}
F2[S]={-S[2],-S[1],S[3]}
F3[S]={-S[3],-S[2],-S[1]}
```

I have no problem writing the functions whenever I want to try a new size stack but my goal is to find the optimal solution 
Then I want to know what functions in what order would resolve the array so it would be contained in a set of arrays SS

To solve the cases of 1-3 I just used a program I wrote that tries every function set but it is 100 lines long and doesn't stop trying when it finds a solution. I can post that for reference if it is at all helpful. Thanks

Comment: Honestly I find your explanation *a bit* confusing.

Comment: `Tuples[{f1, f2, f3}, k]` gives you all possible ways these three functions can be applied `k` times.  `Apply` `Composition` to each list you got from `Tuples` to get the final transformation function you can use with an array.  This is of course an inefficient brute-force method, but according to my reading that is what you were asking about.

Comment: Here's an example to demonistrate, with symbols only this time: `Table[Apply[Composition][f][s], {f, Tuples[{f1, f2, f3}, 2]}]`.  You can break form `Table` or `Map` with `Throw`.